# Eigen compare vectors with some NaN values WITHOUT losing the NaN values

Tags: c++, vector, nan, eigen, comparison-operators

See the code below:

```
    Eigen::VectorXf vec1(3);
    vec1(0) = 231;
    vec1(1) = 512;
    vec1(2) = 213;
    Eigen::VectorXf vec2(3);
    vec2(0) = 10;
    vec2(1) = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    vec2(2) = 2213;

    std::cout << (vec1.array() < vec2.array()) << std::endl;
```

Gives a output of:

0,
0,
1

However I do not want to lose the NaN value so my desired output would be as follows:

0,
nan,
1

I know I can achieve this by looping over the initial vectors, recording the positions of any NaN values, and then updating the output with these positions.

However this is a bit messy and I want the code to be as efficient as possible (i.e. avoid any unnecessary for loops).

So my question is, is there an easy way to achieve this comparison without losing the NaN value?

Comment: I didnt find it in the Eigen docs, but I suppose `operator<` returns `bool`s (I would be surprised if not) and NaN is not a value that a `bool` can have. Why do you think you need NaN as result of comparing two numbers?

Comment: @idclev463035818 in the application I'm building, I read the true values of the vector for some other purpose. If I was to do `not (vec1.array() < vec2.array())` then this would create a true value where the NaN should have been which should not be the case.

Comment: i dont know eigen, so I cannot give an adequate answer, but it seems like you want something like a `enum {True,False,LHS_NaN,RHS_NaN,Both_NaN}` rather than a `bool`. You dont need a second loop but rather a comparison function different from `operator<`

Comment: What is unclear from your question is why you want to avoid loops. Is it out of concern for code clarity ("this is a bit messy") or performance ("as efficient as possible") ?

Comment: @Louen performance. I have tried the equivalent code in a for loop and it was 4/5 times slower

Comment: @idclev463035818 thats a decent idea. I will look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but there are a few things to be aware of.

First is that the **type** of the comparison result will not be the same. The result of component-wise comparison in Eigen will be an array of integers (0 or 1). If you want something that can be 0, 1 or `NaN` you will have to transform it into `float`. In Eigen you have to use an explicit cast operation.

Note that, as pointed by the comments, the result will not tell you which side of the inequality had `NaN`s in the first place.

Now, you can do this arithmetically. If we convert everything to vectors of `float` we can rely on the arithmetic properties of `NaN`s to propagate them :

```
VectorXf compare_with_nans(const VectorXf& vec1, const VectorXf& vec2) {

  const VectorXf zero_or_nan_1 = vec1 - vec1;
  const VectorXf zero_or_nan_2 = vec2 - vec2;

  const VectorXf compare = (vec1.array() < vec2.array()).matrix().cast<float>();

  return compare + zero_or_nan_1 + zero_or_nan2;
}
```

This relies on the fact that `x-x` will yield `0` if `x` is a regular value and `NaN` if `x` is `NaN`, so `vec1-vec1` will have 0 where its component values are regular numbers and `NaN` everywhere else.

With the final addition the `NaN`s  on the `zero_or_nan` vectors will contaminate the regular values on the rows containing `NaN` in the original vector.

Comment: Thank you, this code works exactly as I intended it too. Very creative workaround.

Comment: Be careful though, this feels more like a hack. You might run into trouble with other type of irregular floats (not sure about infinities for example)